# Elixir dependency on local project or private repo

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

I'm new in both Elixir and Phoenix. Currently I have some concern regarding downloading or using library from private or local mix project.
Let say my lib project name is: **my_custom_mix_app** and its an OTP app using **gen_server**. And I want it to be able to do just like below snippet from my phoenix app.

```
defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.2.1"},
    {:phoenix_pubsub, "~> 1.0"},
    {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 3.0"},
    {:mariaex, ">= 0.0.0"},
    {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.6"},
    {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
    {:gettext, "~> 0.11"},
    {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"},
    {:my_custom_mix_app, "~> 1.0"]
end
```

Well since I came from **Java** background, I can do that by using Maven or Gradle, even if the lib project happens to be in my local drive, and not registered in any remote Maven repo.

How can I do that in Elixir?

P.S. I checked this [article](http://yos.io/2016/04/28/writing-and-publishing-elixir-libraries/) regarding creating Elixir deps, but it doesn't solve my concern on a **non registered** lib project

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There two ways to use internal app dependency

**umbrella**

```
defp deps do
    ...
    {:my_app, in_umbrella: true}
end
```

**non-umbrella**

```
defp deps do
    ...
    {:my_app, path: "path/to/the/app"}
    {:my_app_git, git: "https://repo.com/my/app.git}
end
```

Well documented here https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Deps.html

Comment: The path approach works great when your developing a dependency. The dependency is recompiled anytime you restart your main project.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the local path to your project by adding a `path:` key like so:

```
defp deps do
    ...
    {:my_custom_mix_app, path: "path/to/the/app"}
end
```